# Loading messages from resource bundle in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, resourcebundle, ognl

I want to load resource bundle (I have two: one for selected language and another default) dynamically in JSP and read the content in JSP. I have tried following way but its just hard-coded.

```jsp
<s:i18n name="resourcebundle_fr">
   <s:text name="fr_message1" />
</s:i18n>
```

where what I want is instead of `resourcebundle_fr`, I want it to be dynamic.

Also, the same page has included another JSP page which should also pick the messages from the selected language specific resource bundle.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you explain more.

Answer (score 0):

Struts2 tags has support for OGNL. You can use OGNL expressions in the Struts tag's attributes.

```
<s:i18n name="%{resourceBundle}">
  <s:text name="fr_message1" />
</s:i18n>
```

Comment: Its always picking up default resourceBundle even if I do %{resourceBundle}

Comment: You should use getter in the action class that returns desired bundle name.

Comment: getter and setter for what? locale? I have used filter on which I set the locale to action context.